# NX Monorepo 'rootDir' is expected to contain all source files

Tags: node.js, typescript, monorepo, tsconfig, nrwl-nx

I was playing around with NX monorepo NestJS + React. It has a many shared library, for sharing types and DTO-s. I have a setup for TypeORM migrations, which compiles the NestJS project using TSC, not Webpack. It has to be compiled with TSC for Typeorm to notify the database of changes. When I try to compile with TSC or Webpack I get this error:

```
apps/backend/src/app/users/dto/create-user.dto.ts:1:41 - error TS6059: File '/ems/shared/validation/src/index.ts' is not under 'rootDir' '/ems/apps/backend'. 'rootDir' is expected to contain all source files.
    Imported via '@ems/validation' from file '/ems/apps/backend/src/app/users/dto/create-user.dto.ts'
    Imported via '@ems/validation' from file '/ems/apps/backend/src/app/users/users.service.ts'
    Imported via '@ems/validation' from file '/ems/apps/backend/src/app/auth/auth.service.ts'
    Imported via '@ems/validation' from file '/ems/apps/backend/src/app/auth/auth.controller.ts'
```

Here is my root `tsconfig.base.json`:

```json
{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "rootDir": ".",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "importHelpers": true,
    "target": "es2015",
    "module": "esnext",
    "lib": ["es2020", "dom"],
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "skipDefaultLibCheck": true,
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "paths": {
      "@ems/services": ["shared/services/src/index.ts"],
      "@ems/types": ["shared/types/src/index.ts"],
      "@ems/ui": ["shared/ui/src/index.ts"],
      "@ems/validation": ["shared/validation/src/index.ts"]
    }
  },
  "exclude": ["node_modules", "tmp"]
}
```

I tried to reset NX cache, modify tsconfig files, but it doesn' twork.
I tried to remove `rootDir: "."` config from tsconfig, but it doesnt help.